# Что такое Access-Control-Allow-Credentials

Tags: cors

Объясните пожалуйста на русском, зачем нужен cors "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", в инете на английском, и я не понимаю о чем там речь

Comment: так воспользуйтесь переводчиком.

Comment: я всеравно ен понимаю о чем это(
Access-Control-Allow-CredentialsЗаголовок работает в сочетании с XMLHttpRequest.withCredentialsимуществом или с credentialsпараметром в Request()конструкторе Fetch API. Для запроса CORS с учетными данными, чтобы браузеры предоставили ответ на код JavaScript внешнего интерфейса, и сервер (используя Access-Control-Allow-Credentialsзаголовок), и клиент (установив режим учетных данных для запроса XHR, Fetch или Ajax) должны указать, что они решили включить учетные данные.

Comment: тут есть немного с переводом https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B_%D1%81%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B2_%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В общем, CORS - это политика кроссдоменных запросов.  Т.е. когда клиент пытается запросить данные/контент с сервера на другом источнике(англ. "origin").
Представим:

- клиент(например, браузер) у нас на домене `a.com`;
- сервер - `api.b.org`.
  Соответственно, клиент хочет сделать запрос на сервер.
  Если абстрактно говорить, то `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` = `true` в ответе от сервера говорит примерно следующее: "Я(сервер) разрешаю делать такой-то запрос от имени пользователя(с домена `a.com`)".

**А как нам сделать этот запрос от имени пользователя?**

Вот, а пользователь определяется с помощью "[credentials](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#credentials)". В спеке говорится, что credentials - это HTTP cookies, TLS client certificates, and authentication entries (for HTTP authentication). Т.е. как-то надо отправить их от клиента (напр., браузеру) серверу.

**А как сказать браузеру, чтобы он отправил credentials на сервер?**

Возьмем для примера [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).
Так вот одним и параметром есть поле "credentials" и оно имеет одно из трех состояний:

- "omit" - всегда исключает "credentials" для любых запросов.
- "same-origin" - вкл credentials в запрос к тому же origin'у.
- "include" - во все запросы включает credentials.

**Так что же нужно указать на сервере и на клиенте, чтобы всё таки получить данные от сервера?**

Перейдите по этой [ссылке](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-protocol-and-credentials), тут собственно есть табличка, в которой указано, при каких условиях клиент сможет получить данные от сервера.